# ¿Cúal es el mejor control para mostrar una rápida sucesión de imágenes?

Tags: c#, imagen, wpf

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que debe de mostrar al menos 30 imágenes por segundo. Hasta ahora he estado usando un control `Image` pero a medida que aumentan los fps también aumenta la probabilidad de que me dé una excepción del tipo `NotSupportedException`. No sé si es que estoy implementando algo mal o es porque este control tiene sus limitaciones.

Dejo el código que estoy usando por si fuera de ayuda:

```
private void ClientThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        byte[] data = TCPClient.ReceiveData(); // Se bloquea el Thread hasta que recibo la siguiente imagen.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                lock(Display) 
                    Display.Source = ByteToImage(data); // Pinto la nueva imagen.
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException e) // Excepción que suele salir a los 25+ fps
            {
                OnCapturedException.Invoke(new OutputEventArgs("Error interno: " + e.Message));
            }
         }));
    }
}
```